# How can I access to a sub-sub class in Java?

Tags: java, methods, subclass

This is my code summarized:

**Vehicle.java:**

```
public class Vehicle {

    private String enrollment;

    public Vehicle (String enrollment){
        this.enrollment = enrollment;
    }
}
```

**Truck.java:**

```
public class Truck extends Vehicle {

    private double pma;

    public Truck (String enrollment){
       super(enrollment);
    }

    public void setPma(double pma) {
       this.pma = pma;
    }
}
```

**Main.java:**

```
Vehicle[] arrayVehicle = new Vehicle[1];
arrayVehicle[0] = new Truck("AAA333");
arrayVehicle[0].setPma............
```

I can't acces to setPma method. pma is an ONLY attribute of the track, so it mustn't be in the Vehicle class. Then, is there anyway to acces to that method as I want or my structure of classes is wrong?

P.S.: I don't want to put all the code since is an exercise for course i'm enrolled. Ask anything you dont understand about the code or the purpose.

Comment: If you need to access members that aren't in `Vehicle`, you shouldn't be storing an array of `Vehicle`.

Comment: Short of casting, a `Visitor Pattern` is a fairly simply way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrayVehicle[0]` is a variable of type `Vehicle`. So, even if it references an object of type `Truck`, the compiler doesn't know that. The only thing the compiler knows is that `arrayVehicle[0]` is a `Vehicle`. So it doesn't let you access a method that is not defined in the `Vehicle` class.

To access a method defined in Truck, you need a variable of type Truck:

```
Vehicle[] arrayVehicle = new Vehicle[1];
Truck truck = new Truck("AAA333");
arrayVehicle[0] = truck;
truck.setPma(...);
```

Comment: thank you very much, your explanation and example has solved me this and other doubts :)

Answer (score 0):

you should cast back the Vehicle object to the subclass truck to access the subclass methods. You could use reflection and that should work too.

Answer (score -1):

You should put setPMA in the vehicle class.

```
public class Vehicle {

    private String enrollment;

    public Vehicle (String enrollment){
        this.enrollment = enrollment;
    }

    private void setPMA(double pma)
    {
        this.pma = pma;
    }
```

Doing in this, you can access the setPMA in any sub-class.

Comment: I think the is specifically what the OP said that they didn't want to do!